# Upgrading Ember inside of Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've just created a new [Ember-CLI](http://www.ember-cli.com/) app (v0.1.12), and noticed that the referenced version of Ember is v1.8.1 (bower.json).  I'd like to get the [recently released 1.10](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html) goodness in my project.  What steps do I need to take to do this?  (I'm new to Ember, Ember-CLI, Bower & NPM.)

Comment: What version of ember-cli are you using?

Comment: @Oren, v0.1.12... what appears to be the latest.

Comment: Went to SO tonight to ask _this_ question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the release notes for Ember 1.10.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html)

> To smoothly upgrade to 1.10 and HTMLBars, Ember-CLI users should
>   update to a version at or after 0.1.12 and then remove their
>   application's Handlebars dependency.

You can do this by following the steps below:

1) Delete your `bower_components` folder

2) run `bower install --save ember#beta` to get the latest beta of Ember (you can specify the version if you want a specific version)

3) run `bower install` to reinstall your bower dependencies

4) Uninstall handlebars: `npm uninstall --save-dev broccoli-ember-hbs-template-compiler`

5) Install HTMLbars: `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-htmlbars`

Comment: Do you know if upgrading the ember-data to the latest beta is a similar process?

Comment: With regards to installing using bower, yes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the steps listed by Oren, you will want to make this change to your `Brocfile.js` so that you can remove the Handlebars dependency from your `bower.json` file as well:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  vendorFiles: {
    'handlebars.js': null
  }
});
```

[Source](https://github.com/rwjblue/components-in-subdirs/commit/78e7ed2d072f42d9cf0fd3d9fc2376f106ab762e)