# Call an action without any interaction

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to call an controller action without interaction within a template?

I want to convert a number to an specific string like this:

```
switch (s){
    case 1: return "foo";
    case 2: return "bar";
    // ...
}
```

I want to do this in an `each` loop => `each` over items from my model, convert property `s` from each item to a specific string.

Well I probably could do this in an `afterModel` hook - but I would like to do it from the template.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a bound helper. That can have your logic to convert from the string to whatever string you want to display.

See [Register Bound Helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper) in the docs.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('convertToMyString', function(s) {
    switch (s){
        case 1: return "foo";
        case 2: return "bar";
        // ...
    }
});
```

And in your template:

```
{{convertToMyStringname model.s}}
```

Comment: Hmm.. That was exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain how I can use it as an html attribute? Like this: `<i class={{convert m.S}}></i>` => It seems I can't use [bind-attr](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/) with a bound helper

Comment: What version of ember are you using?

Comment: You should be able to use a bound helper for a class name in a version of Ember > 1.10 (without the `bind-atr` helper). So you have a few options, 1) upgrade 2) do the conversion process in your controller/component.

Comment: I've upgraded to 1.10.0 and get   
`Uncaught Error: Bound attributes are not yet supported in Ember.js `

Comment: I'm not sure you upgraded correctly. Bound attributes are definitely supported in 1.10 -- see http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html Try running the steps detailed in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/28441907/77074

Comment: I don't use any JS package manager. Ember Inspector also indicates that I use 1.10.0.

Comment: The fact that you don't use a package manager may be part of the problem. Have you verified t hat HTMLBars was pulled in correctly -- that is the piece that eliminates the need for bind-atr and enables this functionality.

Comment: Yeah it's pulled in. I've tried to use the CDN files - as described [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html). Still the same error. Weird..

Comment: Okay - I've found the 'error'. The feature is first available in 1.11 beta. Thanks for your help so far ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't, you are working against the framework and all you'll find is hardship.

Do your data processing (decoration/formatting) in your controller and from there make your data available to your template.

Templates are presentation only, no logic should be performed there (as less as possible actually).

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  processedData: function() {
    return // processed data;
  }.property('model')
});
```